# Failing to figure out macro call chain from biblatex-dw or biblatex-juradiss

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-dw

Which file contains the original definitions of the `biblatex` macros `name:last-first` or `author/editor`?

I am terribly stuck here customizing the `.cbx` and `.bbx` files from `biblatex-juradiss`, which is based on `authortitle` from the `biblatex-dw` package, which is based on `biblatex`. The problem is, even reading those `.cbx` and `.bbx` files I cannot figure out where the font for the editor field is actually set and how to influence this. All I see are calls to the above macros, or `\printnames{editor}` directives, but nothing that actually sets a font. The only `\DeclareNameFormat{editor}` directive I have found so far is in my own `.cbx` but this only checks the uniqueness of editor's first and last names and never sets a font. Still the editors come out in italics, and I need them to be normal.

Answer (score 1):

Most definitions of the standard styles happen in `biblatex.def` and `standard.bbx`.

Many styles load these two files internally and rely on the commands defined there, though they may of course re-define many of them. (Some styles may not load `standard.bbx`, but `biblatex.def` is loaded by default.)

In `authortitle-dw.bbx` you will find

```
\DeclareBibliographyOption{namefont}[normal]{%
  \ifcsdef{bbx@opt@namefont@#1}
    {\csuse{bbx@opt@namefont@#1}}
    {\blxdw@error{%
       Invalid option 'namefont=#1'\MessageBreak
       Valid values are 'normal', 'smallcaps', 'italic', 'bold'}}}
\newcommand{\bbx@namefont}{}
\def\bbx@opt@namefont@normal{%
  \renewcommand{\bbx@namefont}{}}
\def\bbx@opt@namefont@smallcaps{%
  \renewcommand{\bbx@namefont}{\textsc}}
\def\bbx@opt@namefont@italic{%
  \renewcommand{\bbx@namefont}{\mkbibemph}}
\def\bbx@opt@namefont@bold{%
  \renewcommand{\bbx@namefont}{\mkbibbold}}


\DeclareBibliographyOption{firstnamefont}[normal]{%
  \ifcsdef{bbx@opt@firstnamefont@#1}
    {\csuse{bbx@opt@firstnamefont@#1}}
    {\blxdw@error{%
       Invalid option 'firstnamefont=#1'\MessageBreak
       Valid values are 'normal', 'smallcaps', 'italic', 'bold'}}}
\newcommand{\bbx@firstnamefont}{}
\def\bbx@opt@firstnamefont@normal{%
  \renewcommand{\bbx@firstnamefont}{}}
\def\bbx@opt@firstnamefont@smallcaps{%
  \renewcommand{\bbx@firstnamefont}{\textsc}}
\def\bbx@opt@firstnamefont@italic{%
  \renewcommand{\bbx@firstnamefont}{\mkbibemph}}
\def\bbx@opt@firstnamefont@bold{%
  \renewcommand{\bbx@firstnamefont}{\mkbibbold}}
```

Which implements options to influence the name font. The default is `normal`.

`\bbx@namefont` and `\bbx@firstnamefont` are then used in the redefinitions of `\mkbibnamelast`, `\mkbibnamefirst`, `\mkbibnameprefix` and `\mkbibnameaffix`, those four macros define the font used to print different parts of the name.

But `biblatex-juradiss.bbx` loads `\RequireCitationStyle{authortitle-dw}%` and then has

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{%
%nopublisher=false,
namefont=italic,% Format für Nachnamen (biblatex-dw)
firstnamefont=italic,% Format für Vornamen (biblatex-dw)
edstringincitations=false,% Kein (Hrsg) im Fußnoten-Zitat (biblatex-dw)
}%
```

So it sets the option to print names in italics.

You could just issue

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{%
  namefont=normal,
  firstnamefont=normal,
}%
```

in your document to get names in normal font.

Comment: That would work, but would also convert the author's names to normal font. However my publisher's style guide demands that the author's names should remain in italics. Is there a way to influence the font setting for output of name lists directly before this output is generated? I have already tried 
`\DeclareNameFormat{editor}
\textit{
...
}}`
which lifts the italic formatting of the editor names, but makes the slashes separating them italic, which look ugly.

Comment: @Michael That is something different then. You can ask a new question for that. Please make sure to provide a working example. My trial with `biblatex-juradiss` and an editor work didn't go down well (I get to see the last name twice: once in italics and once normally). (PS: If you want help with a specific task it is better to make that clear in the question immediately instead of just asking about general definitions and such. It would also have been useful to explain that authors on the other hand need to be italic.)